# Why does grep not work?

Tags: grep

I am trying to find all files in my directory, which contain the string "<3".  Doing this should be simple:

```
grep "<3" *
```

However, running this prints

```
grep: <3: No such file or directory
```

and then proceeds to grep all files for something else...  (I'm not sure what exactly, but lines show up containing no 3's at all...)

CAUSE: apparently there was a file `-f` in my directory, and when it's getting passed into grep with the `*`, grep is treating it as a flag, causing this behaviour.

Trying to delete this file normally also doesn't work, since `rm` treats it as a flag as well. Thanks to a suggestion from Nick, this file can be removed with

```
rm ./-f
```

Comment: Grep shouldn't be used for this.  You can use `find` `locate` `for i in /path/` but `grep` is generally for searching output and not so much for files.  EDIT:  I think you are trying to search for content within the files?  In which case I believe you would have to `cat` them first.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `grep` to search files' contents.

Comment: @Jesse_b Yes, I am searching within files.  But I believe grep should work without `cat`ing.  I mean, I wouldn't even mind doing that, but grep won't display filenames that matched in that case.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Yes that is what I said :p.  His question is worded strange:  `How to grep all files in a directory?` instead of `How to grep the contents of all files in a directory?`.  Either way he should have to cat the files first in order to grep the contents, no?

Comment: @Jesse_b, `cat`ing into `grep` is bad practice; don't suggest this.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thanks, did not know that.  His command doesn't work for me because it needs a single quote around `<3` to escape the `<` . Works fine for me as:  `grep '<3' ./*`

Comment: grep *is* the right tool for this. To the OP: `grep "<3" *` should work fine. The fact that it complains that <3 cannot be found, suggests that there is something in the space between them that is misinterpreted as the pattern: maybe you have some sort of invisible character in there?

Comment: `rm ./-f` should work to remove the errant file.

Comment: @Nick Thanks!  I'll update the post, giving you credit.

Comment: When there is a solution, either ask the person to write the answer, or write yourself the answer. Then mark it/accept it as the solution. Please do not edit the answer in the question, please do not add solved to the title.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro OK, I'll do it.  Though you should have left this comment before modifying my post, since now I modified it right back, before I read your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grep "<3" -- *
```

With `--` you can determine the end of the options and the beginning of the positional arguments for many GNU programs. Thus a file `-l` does not cause any harm.

An alternative is

```
grep "<3" ./*
```

Comment: I would like to point out that, this can also be used to delete the `-f` file.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to replicate:

```
$ echo '<3' > foo
$ grep "<3" *
foo:<3
```